# I want to add new values ​to all elements of a category

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to insert new values ​​to all the elements of my column "meta_value", here is the code that I thought was good but it shows me an error:

@Hrishi In fact I'm trying to update already existing data, I target specific meta_key (order_by_first_post) which I want to  initialize all the corresponding values ​​of the column 'meta_value' to zero here's an image of my base:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJlkC.png)

```
insert into wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
select ID, 'order_by_first_post', '0'
from wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'recipes';
```

Thank you all for your help, that's what I expected, I'll try to be clearer in my questions next time:

```
    INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT wp_posts.ID, 'order_by_first_post', '0'
FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' and wp_posts.post_type = 'recipes'";
```

Comment: What is the error? can you post here please.
you want to update the existing meta values with new values or Insert a new record ?

Comment: The syntax looks fine? I'm betting there's a unique constraint on `(post_id, meta_key)` and this sql is trying to insert dups.